# Message Loss (message sent to spring-amqp doesn't get published to rabbitmq)

Tags: spring-amqp, codahale-metrics

We are having a setup where we are using spring-amqp transacted channels to push our messages to RabbitMq. During a testing we found that messages were not even getting published from spring-amqp to rabbitmq;
we suspect `metricsCollector.basicPublish(this)` in `com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN` failure(no exception is thrown).
[image]

because we can see that `RabbitUtils.commitIfNecessary(channel)` in `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate` is not getting called when there is an issue executing `metricsCollector.basicPublish(this)` for the same code flow.

We have taken TCP dumps and could see that message were written to stream/socket on rabbitmq, but since commit didn't happen due to an a probable amqp api failure the messages were not delivered to corresponding queues.

Jars Version Being used in the setup:-

1. spring-amqp-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar,
2. spring-rabbit-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar
3. amqp-client-5.7.3.jar,
4. metrics-core-3.0.2.jar

Is anyone facing the similar issue?
Can someone please help.

---edit 1
(Setup) :- We are using same connection Factory for flows with parent transaction and flows not running with parent transactions

On further analyzing the issue , we found that `isChannelLocallyTransacted` is sometimes showing in-consistent behavior because `ConnectionFactoryUtils.isChannelTransactional(channel, getConnectionFactory()` is sometimes having a reference to transacted channel (returns true hence expression `isChannelLocallyTransacted` evaluates to false) due to which tx.commit never happens; so message gets lost before getting committed to RabbitMQ.

[image]

Comment: Please post a complete, simple, example that exhibits this behavior so we can take a look. Spring has no knowledge on whether a metrics collector is configured so I don't see how or why the commit would not be called.

Comment: Hi Gary, I have updated my question to include more details on setup and point of failure.

Comment: I don't see how that's possible; as I said I need a complete example that exhibits the behavior. This code has been in place for over a decade.